# unable to find date difference using getTime() y?

Tags: javascript

i wrote code like this.but it is not giving proper out put.in this code output should be -1.but it is giving -31 y?

```
var start= new Date("04/09/2014");
var end= new Date("03/09/2014");
var d1=start.getTime();
var d2=end.getTime();
var difference = Math.round((d2-d1)/(1000*60*60*24));
if(difference<0){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = difference ;
}
```

Comment: Is this meant to be Java or Javascript? They're different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses the date format mm/dd/yyyy, but you're entering it as dd/mm/yyyy.

The better approach, as commented by @cloudfeet: "It's a bad idea to use locality-specific date formats anyway. Stick to YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601)."

Comment: It's a bad idea to use locality-specific date formats anyway.  Stick to `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO 8601)

Comment: @cloudfeet Absolutely.

Comment: Fancy adding that to the answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid these kind of problems, it is better to use the syntax Date(year, month, day). Note that the month is zero based!

So, your first two lines become:

```
var start = new Date(2014, 8, 4);  
var end = new Date(2014, 8, 3);
```

Comment: Seriously, zero-based months are just the worst idea ever. >_<

Comment: True, but it seems ISO 8601 is only supported by IE9+ so I will stick with this format for a little while.

Comment: Good point - if you're in a browser environment (non-modern), that's something to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't used english locale, dates are in format MM/DD/YYYY.